# I installed the package on my React Native folder project, but always seems like this: EPERM

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I installed the package on my React Native folder project, but always seems like this:

[image]

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing packages, you have to stop the metro server first.

When the server is running, it doesn't find the module you've installed.

So after stopping the server, reopen it by running

```sh
$ react-native start
```

and in another terminal run

```sh
$ react-native run-android
```

If the error still exists, then do the following:

```sh
$ rm -rf node_modules/
$ npm i
$ react-native start
$ react-native run-android # run this command in the different terminal.
```

Comment: @OvaldyDwifyR, my pleasure. :D